# FCM topic notifications being received on emulator but no other device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having an issue where Firebase Cloud Messaging will send notifications to the emulator (Android 7.0, with play services installed) but not to any device (Google Pixel 2, Samsung s9+ , Huawei MATE 10) running Android 8+. I initially thought it might have been a power saving issue closing off the listener but even when I remove optimisation from the app, it still doesn't come through.

I know the downstream request is being sent successfully and I'm receiving status code `200` from the response (and of course because the notification is being received on the emulator). When debugging on the devices however, the `onMessageReceived` in my `FCMService` class is not being called at all, whether in the foreground or background.

It's definitely registered in the manifest and each device is using the same version of the application:

```
<service android:name=".services.FCMService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

If there is any more information required, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why was this happening?**

I realised when I entered the version numbers into the question that it would have to do with Android Oreo. I was searching for issues with FCM and not recent changes the how notifications work. In Android 26+, [notification channels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels) have been introduced and are required if your app is targeting 26 and above (which I was). Because I updated the target SDK without thinking, I of course got hit with no notifications.

**How to fix it**

The easiest way is to just target API 25 but that's not ideal.

What you can do is register notification channels. I've done this where I handle my notifications (so `onMessageReceived`) as it doesn't register the same channel more than once.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    // Set the default notification channel settings to be that of alert
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
    String channel_id = ALERT_CHANNEL_ID;
    CharSequence channel_name = ALERT_CHANNEL_NAME;
    String channel_desc = ALERT_CHANNEL_DESC;

    // Logic to change the channel id, name and desc if required

    // Build and modify channel settings
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channel_id, channel_name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(channel_desc);
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.enableVibration(true);

    // Create the notification channel
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

Then you want to change the notification builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
```

Comment: You are right. Changing target API is not the best solution because we all have to meet Google Play's target API level requirement. Reference: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk. Today, the lowest level to create new apps and upgrade existing apps is 29.